# The else part is not working when the if-statement fails. How can i solve this issue?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

```
    async function loginUser(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        const response  = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/login/',{
            method:'POST',
            headers:{
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
            },
            body : JSON.stringify({
                email,
                password,
            }),
        })
        const data = await response.json();
        if(data.user){
            localStorage.setItem("token",data.user);
            // window.location.href = "./CustomerDashboard"; 
        }else{
            console.log("Invalid Credentials");
            toast.error("Login failed");
        }
        console.log(data);
    }
```

Here the else statement not working. Also the **console.log(data)** after the if-statement works only if the if-statement satisfies otherwise it is not executing.

Comment: Any errors in the console? Sounds like `await response.json()` or `data.user` is throwing an error.

Comment: You have no error handling in your code, the most likely scenario here is that one of the awaits throws and then the branch is never reached. See [`try...catch` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#promise_rejection).

Comment: @VLAZ I have checked the console and there are no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Do console.log( response ) immediately after the fetch to see what you got.   You are flying blind right there.  You have to look at the whole response object.  Once you see what that looks like, you can hit the docs for whatever fetch library you are using and see how to handle response correctly.  I've normally used one that had a finally block so if it failed I could do something.

response.json() is guaranteed to fail at some points, no matter how you slice it, because not every api call with in fact return json, or even a body.